# request headers not submitted during post request using the WiFlyHQ lib

Tags: arduino

using the WiFlyHQ library i try to send an POST request, it seems like the request header get cropped, if i inspect the request on the server i can see the following:

```
headers: { host: 'localhost:3000', 'content-type': 'application' },
```

with this  setup;

```
void SendJasonPacket()
  {
    wifly.open(Server, ServerPort);
    wifly.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
    wifly.println("Host: localhost:3000");
    wifly.println("Content-type: application/json");
    wifly.println("Accept: application/json");
    wifly.println("Content-Length: 93");
    wifly.println("User-Agent: easyNAM/0.0.1");
    wifly.println("{'checkin':{'device_token': '122','card_token': '12312', 'timestamp': '2012-10-29T14:31:03'}}");
    wifly.close();
  }
```

i tried a couple of different headers, that's what i got:

```
  headers: { 'user-agent': 'easyNAM/0.0.1', accept: 'application/j' },
  headers: { accept: 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'easyNAM/0' },
  headers: { host: 'localhost:3000', 'content-type': 'application' },
```

it seems, that it get cropped after a specific character count, not sure what i did wrong here....

Answer (score 0):

I believe memory is the issue, i ran into the same issue.  I am using VS 2012 to build my app and when it reaches 60% it tends to act sporadically.